# Couchbase 2.2.0 document size editing limit

Tags: couchbase

I tried to edit document via couchbase console, and caught this warning message:

> Warning: Editing of document with size more than 2.5kb is not allowed

How can I increase max editing document size?

Comment: Try using `curl` from the command line. Does that work?

Comment: Haven't curl module. Should I install it?

Comment: Or the equivalent, yes. (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: doesn't work. I think there must be some config for this thing.

Comment: Alternatively: copy and paste the doc's ulr to the browser after retrieving from dev tools

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can raise the limit or disable completely on version 2.2:

**To raise the limit**;

edit file:  `/opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/js/documents.js`

at line 214:

```
var DocumentsSection = {

  docsLimit: 1000,

  docBytesLimit: 2500,

init: function () {

var self = this;
```

Edit the `docBytesLimit` variable set to `2500` and increase it to your preferred value.

**To disable completely;**

You can comment out the conditional statement and return a false value.
At line 362 comment out the statement and return false:

```
function isJsonOverLimited(json) {
  //return getStringBytes(json) > self.docBytesLimit;
  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.. There are limitations as to how much your WYSYWIG editor can handle. So please be careful and as always editing core files can have negative results. We did it on our system and it works for us.

Comment: It would be nice in the couchbase team make this setting editable via the admin console, because in some cases, users wouldnt be able to tweak this setting (ie dont have access to the js file)

Comment: Do we need to restart or do something after editing the documents.js ? Because I have to do this in a live running CouchDB server.

Comment: As of release 3.0 the file structure has changed; file can now be found at this new location: /opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/js/documents.js edit for size can be made at line 209, or disabled at line 363

Comment: I did this on the fly by setting a breakpoint in chrome console and running a command to change self.docBytesLimit to whatever I wanted.

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon I don't think you have to restart.

Comment: I can confirm NO restart is required.

Comment: This is such a stupidly low limit, I wish they'd wake up and realize we don't run on a 486  :/

Comment: It's Working.Nice suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the UI code will actually make the request and get the document back, but *then* refuse to show it if it's too big. So, you can actually just open up the browser developer tools, find the request for the document you want in the network traffic, and the document itself is right there in the response. Copy-paste into a pretty-printer, and you're done.

Comment: Great hack! Well found

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution to view data

Answer (score 8):

for Mac OSX, u can edit

```
/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/js/documents.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase console is here to help you, but when you deal with large data it is better to use a SDK and modify your document using some code. You can find all the SDKs here:
http://www.couchbase.com/develop

Is is possible with your environment?

Answer (score 0):

If i read the code correctly it's seems like a hard code value in the UI code http://review.couchbase.org/#/c/22678/2/priv/public/js/documents.js

Answer (score 0):

On Windows in Couchbase Server 3.0.3 this file is located at
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\lib\ns_server\priv\public\js

Answer (score 0):

As of Couchbase 4.5 you have to modify the app.min.js file not the documents.js. To permanently fix try:

`sed -i 's|return getStringBytesFilter(json)>docBytesLimit;|return false;|' /opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/ui/app.min.js`

Comment: I just changed constant("docBytesLimt",256*1024) to 8096*1024

Answer (score 0):

Since couchbase 4.5 you need to update the following `app.min.js` file to view the documents larger than 2.5Kb.

```
vi /opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/ui/app.min.js
```

search for the word `docBytesLimit` within the file using below command. This will show you all the occurrences in highlighted color.

```
/\<docBytesLimit/>
```

Find the text `constant("docBytesLimit",256*1024)` within above occurrences and replace the 256 with the value you needed.

Finally `restart the couchbase server`