# couchbase can't store because too big

Tags: python, couchbase

We are using python to store documents into couchbase.

we get this error message coming from couchbase.

```
_TooBigError_0x4 (generated, catch TooBigError): <Key=u'1426714751', RC=0x4[The object requested is too big to store in the server], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src\multiresult.c,309)>
```

how can i change the maximum size?

i'm using couchbase python SDK version 2.0

Comment: @Carsten [Couchbase 2.2.0 document size editing limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090611/couchbase-2-2-0-document-size-editing-limit) is talking about the UI limit. This is a limit on the data path between the SDK and the server.

Comment: @Paddy Sorry, my bad. I retracted my closevote. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum document size in Couchbase is 20MB for Couchbase buckets and 1MB for Memcached buckets. There's no way to change that, so if you're hitting this limit, you will need to change your data modelling to split up your documents into smaller objects.