# Warning: Editing of document with size more than 256 KiB is not allowed

Tags: couchbase

Solution tested for Couchbase Server 4.5 and Ubuntu 14.04

Since version 4.5 this solution does not work anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19733599/742855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vim /opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/ui/app.min.js`
`/docBytesLimit`
edit and save

Answer from support:

> In Couchbase Server 4.5.0 we ship with a new UI, and the value for docBytesLimit is set in a different location (`/opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/ui/app/constants/constants.js` in 4.5.0 vs. `/opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/js/documents.js` for the old UI).
>   There is a slight complication with the new UI, in that for performance reasons the JavaScript code is "minified" and the above constants.js is actually bundled in to `/opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/ui/app.min.js` when we build the Couchbase Server package.
>   If you want to change the value for docBytesLimit you can either edit `app.min.js` directly, or you can edit `constants.js` and load the UI without using the "minified" version of the JavaScript by adding `minified=false` to the URL you use to connect to your cluster:
>   `http://my.couchbase.cluster:8091/ui/index.html?minified=false`
>   There will be a slight delay the first time you connect using this method.
>   Please bear in mind that any changes you make to these files are completely unsupported, and that the changes will likely be lost when you perform an upgrade.